# How to make faster the loading of the user's profile photo (Firebase, swift)

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

I had this in the viewDidLoad of my ProfileViewController

```
 self.user = Auth.auth().currentUser
      self.databaseRef.child("user_profiles").child(self.user!.uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot:DataSnapshot) in

          let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary


        if(snapshotValue?["about"] != nil)
        {

        }

        if(snapshotValue?["profile_pic"] != nil)
        {
            let databaseProfilePic = snapshotValue!["profile_pic"]
                as! String

            let data = try? Data(contentsOf: URL(string: databaseProfilePic)!)

            self.setProfilePicture(imageView: self.profilePic,imageToSet: UIImage (data:(data!))!)
        }
```

with also this function

```
 internal func setProfilePicture(imageView:UIImageView,imageToSet:UIImage)
    {

        imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 22.5
        imageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        imageView.image = imageToSet

    }
```

to load the profile picture of the authenticated users. My only problem is that every time i go into my ProfileViewController it takes 3-4 seconds to load the picture while i would like that as on instagram, whatsapp etc. the image is already loaded, so there is no such annoying waiting time. How can i do?

Comment: check this -: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40873685/how-to-cache-images-using-urlsession-in-swift , use NSCache .

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46199203/downloading-uiimage-via-alamofireimage/46199246#46199246

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for fast download image async you can use this [library](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher)

and you can simply download image with less line of code

```
if(snapshotValue?["profile_pic"] as? String != nil) {
   if let imgUrl = URL(string:snapshotValue?["profile_pic"] as! String) 
   {
       self.profilePic.kf.setImage(with: imgUrl)
       self.profilePic.layer.cornerRadius = min(self.profilePic.frame.height,self.profilePic.frame.width) / 2 //you can change the cornerRadius according to your need
       self.profilePic.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
       self.profilePic.layer.masksToBounds = true
   }
}
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: thanks i added this library, now it saying to me "Value of type 'UIImageView' has no member 'kf'" what i miss?

Comment: clean(command+shift+k) then run that will work  and don't forget to import KingFisher

Comment: Could not cast value of type 'Swift.String' to 'Kingfisher.Resource'

Comment: what is your project swift version and kingfisher pod version?

Comment: i'm with swift4 and pod 'Kingfisher', '~> 4.0'

Comment: sorry ganesh i wrote last think to you in chat

Comment: no issues, answer updated for your requirement check it once